# Multiple EC2 Keys on new instances

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

What is the recommended way to give multiple admins access to the EC2 instances in an Elastic Beanstalk environment?

As far as I can tell there seems to be no way to specify multiple values for aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:EC2KeyName

Would I need to manage my own set of SSH private keys and load them in from S3 or somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you will need to manage this yourself.  This is usually what configuration management systems are for, or you can bake them into your containers.

Comment: Thanks @KarenB It's a bit disappointing, as this seems like a it should be a relatively simple feature for AWS to add, and it would make things much easier.